# Dynamics CRM 2016: Web Resource display based on status

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

This is for Dynamics CRM 2016. Im sure this is a simple task, but i dont have any JS (javascript) knowledge. I basiclly want to add a web resource on the case form (OnLoad and OnSave) to display certain text based on the status reason. So a single html file which would use JS to check the status reason of the entity to use the following simple logic.

- If its "In-Progress" then display in-progress, using a large yellow font.
- If its "Waiting for info" then display "Paused", using a large red color font.
- If its "pending to close" or "resolved" then hide, as in dont display anything.

I just need the idea, ill adjust the font and color and addtional IF's as needed.

Oh... did i mention i dont have any JS knowledge...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It’s too broad. Check it out if you can use [notification](https://www.powerobjects.com/2015/09/23/dynamics-crm-alert-and-notification-javascript-methods/) instead of HTML in iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Load your `JS` and `HTML` files on the form by adding them in the from customization.
Then use below script in your `JS` file to get the status reason from opened CRM record.

```
var status = window.parent.xrm.page.data.entity.attributes.get("statuscode").Value();
```

Hopefully, it will resolve your problem.